# error: Uncaught TypeError: .map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

im having problem fetching api with .map function

i always got error (Apasih.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: dataProduk.map is not a function).

can someone please help me solve this problem?

here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import List_products from './List_products';



const Apasih = () => {
  const [dataProduk, setDataProduk] = useState([]);



 useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(')
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('data API', result.data);
        const responseAPI = result.data;

        setDataProduk(responseAPI.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('error: ', err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {dataProduk.map((produk) => {
        return <List_products key={produk.id} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Apasih;
```

Comment: Did you log the value of `dataProduk` before using `.map` ?
The error clearly states that the function `.map` does not exist on dataProduk so it implies it's not an array.

Comment: im pretty sure thts an array. i looked up the console and it showed up as an array list of data that i want. but it just doesn't work, and i dont know why :(

Comment: Log `console.log(dataProduk);` right before the return statement. You need to be sure not just pretty sure ;).

Answer (score 0):

dataProduk is either an object, or undefined, you are assigning result.data.data are you sure that is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You first need validated if the response is a Array, for example, the request code is 200 and that is ok but the data should be null or the response would change the type of the useState.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if it's not empty and it's also an Array, i.e

```
!(data && Array.isArray(data))? null : <SomeComponent />
```

Always use this logic to prevent subsequent Errors or crashes when dealing with Arrays in your projects.